# MVC in Visual Studio Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I got Visual Studio 2010 Express C# Edition. I'm using WinXP as OS.

How do I get ASP.Net MVC in it? I saw another question that stated that MVC was included automatically, but I cannot find it anywhere. I've also tried by installing MVC3 RC2. Didn't show up either.

Isn't it possible to use MVC with Express edition?

(I've also got VS 2008 Professional on the same computer)

**Edit**

I needed the Visual Studio Web Developer Edition to get MVC2.

But how do I get MVC3?

**Edit 2**

I have XP Home edition which is not supported by web platform installer since IIS is not included. I guess that's why MVC3 wont install in Visual Studio 2010 Express (although it installed fine on my computer which is a bit strange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't it possible to use MVC with Express edition?

Sure is. I installed VS2010 web express edition and when I choose New Project then it shows the MVC2 web application and empty web application project template. Last week I also installed MVC3 RC via the [web platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=MVC3) and that shows up too.

Comment: The link you provided gives me *"The product you are trying to install is not supported on your operating system"*.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? I tried it both on Windows 7 and Windows XP professional.

Comment: NOTE: You have to go to File--> New Project.  MVC3 does NOT show up on the start screen or under File--> New Website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly download MVC 3 RC2 from here and install it:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=955d593e-cbd1-4ed1-88eb-02ff79dd74d8